# Save image from custom camera in specific URI

Tags: android, camera, save

I am receive an URI from my Activity. I want to be able to save a picture from my Custom Camera into that specific location, I don't know how to achieve that. Can I get some help?
I see how to save an image from the Google developer website but they create a folder, name the picture with date and etc. I have an URI which contains all the information. All I need to do is to save a picture in that URI.

Initially, I am trying to achieve manually what the camera intent does when you add this extra:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, URI_GOES_HERE);
```

Here is the code in the current Activity where the URI is passed to my Custom Camera as an Extra:

```
String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
                preDefinedCameraUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                            values);
                Log.d("Predefined URI:","" + preDefinedCameraUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, preDefinedCameraUri);
```

How do I save the picture in that extra?

Comment: Hmm, so it sounds like this should work... but I guess it doesn't. What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @hichris123 I don't understand your answer. What should work? I have no code that should work, I don't even know where to start. All I gave was a piece of code that a Camera intent knows how to handle, but since I have a custom camera, I want to be able to handle that on my own (save the picture in the location passed in the extra)